# Export Excel settings to a file

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I have customized Ms Excel  to my needs, for example I have written small macros and attached them as buttons to the quick access toolbar, made the Developer tab visible etc.)

Is there any way to export these settings to a file?

So that;

I can use the same settings on different computers I work,

Restore my settings when needed

Distribute to people who ask for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel you can backup several parts of the configuration individually. To back them all up you'd need to create a migration profile using something like the file and settings transfer wizard.

Ribbon customizations can be exported to a file. Right click on the ribbon, select Customize Ribbon, and in the lower right section of the window there is an Import/Export button.

The macros themselves are stored where you choose to store them and you can migrate these as well pretty simply.

Many of the other settings are stored in the registry. Most are per-user and so are stored here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Excel.

Others would be stored in HKLM...

Comment: This answer is outdated and incorrect.

Comment: @ashleedawg If you look at the tags applied to the question, this question applies to Windows 7 and Excel 2007 and 2010. Settings may change for different versions of Windows and Excel, but as this question states the specific version(s) is applies to, it is highly unlikely the answer has changed.