# Upgrading Office 2010 to 2016 - How to save settings and customizations?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2016

We are about to upgrade from Office 2010 to 2016 (including Outlook).   Our IT dept says this requires an uninstall of 2010 because of the way our license bundling works.   My question is:  how do I preserve as much of my current set-up as possible during the transfer?    I want to save such settings as preferences, styles, recent documents, templates, email signatures & settings, etc.

How much can be saved?  Is there a guide for copying, saving and/or exporting my current Office 2010 settings and bringing them back into Office 2016?

UPDATE: Post install, I have lost custom styles in Word as well as pinned & recent files.

Notes: The new installation will initially be on Windows 7 (upgrade to Windows 10 will follow within 6 months).  The existing installation is on Microsoft Exchange with active directory.  New installation will be on Exchange + One Drive

Comment: Your IT department should take care of all of that as part of the migration process. If they don't then fire them ;)

Comment: While you can some of those settings, things like recent documents, can't be kept.  This seems like a question for your IT Department, anything that can be saved, would require them.

Comment: They said they're not supporting any sort of transfer of settings and I should expect a complete wipe and refresh.  They also said I was welcome to try on my own and let them know how it worked.

Comment: Your email signatures are based on your profile, which will be kept, after the upgrade.  templates you might have used will still exist, you might have to make Office 2016 aware of them, but they will still exist.  Recent documents list will be wiped for obvious reasons.  More specific examples of what your looking to save would be required to comment on those.

Comment: This answer might be helpful...[How to migrate Microsoft Office settings](http://superuser.com/a/543022/97028)

Comment: Thanks, Ramhound.  I went ahead with the install and most of the settings came along.  I did lose some Custom Word styles, which has affected some of the documents they were used in, oddly.  Pinned and recent files are gone.

Comment: I know this is too little too late, but … when my workplace upgraded from Office 2003 to 2007, I found a tool to export a lot of Office settings to a file, from which they could be imported after the upgrade. This was part of the default installation; I didn’t have to download it from anywhere. Naturally, the IT department didn’t know about it (or, at least, they didn’t tell us). I don’t recall any more than that (from ten years ago!). I’m posting this to encourage people by stating that such tools do (or did) exist; you may be able to find them if you look hard enough.